# Match exact words in VSCode

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

I'm doing a find and replace in VSCode for some CSS classes and I'm running into the following issue when matching for the word `row`. It finds `row` successfully, but I'm trying to avoid it from also matching things like `row-label`. Is there a way to match strings that only includes things such as `row` and `.row`?

Comment: Is this good enough for your test cases: `(?<!\w)(row)[^-\w]`  https://regex101.com/r/tUMNOu/3

Comment: Strangely that still matches `row` included in hyphens with VSCode

Comment: Try `(?<![\w-])(row)[^-\w]`, I made a small change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `(?<![\w-])(row)[^-\w]`

Negative lookbehind to eliminate `\w` or `-` from immediately preceding `row`.

And following character cannot be `\w` or `-`.

[Rex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/tUMNOu/4)

---

If necessary to avoid `row` followed by characters such as `!` or `$` etc. you could use

`(?<![\w-])(row)[^-\w!@$%^&*)_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.\/?]`

https://regex101.com/r/tUMNOu/10